# How do I store a custom field type settings for checkboxes?

Tags: entities, 8

I have already created my field_type,field_widget, field_formatter  using Drupal [console](https://hechoendrupal.gitbooks.io/drupal-console/content/en/commands/generate-plugin-fieldtype.html) and also a set of checkboxes options to appear in field settings, I get this all working but when I select few options and save the settings it isn't storing those values , so when I go back again to field_settings I see the previously checked options are empty.

```
 public function storageSettingsForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $has_data) {
$elements = [];

$elements['cars'] = array(
  '#type' => 'checkboxes',
  '#title' => t('Types of cars?'),
  '#options' => array('ferari' => t('Ferari'), 'prius' => t('Prius'), 'jaguar' => t('Jaguar'), 'lamborghini' => t('Lamborghini')),
  '#default_value' => $this->getSetting('cars'),
);
return $elements;}
```

This is a sample piece of code of mine, I need a way of storing the values that I check on the options.

Comment: change $elements = []; to $elements = array(); and try apart all is well.

Comment: `[]` is perfectly valid in the PHP version required to run Drupal 8; that is not surely the problem, nor does it make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `defaultFieldSettings()` method in your class:

```
public static function defaultFieldSettings() {
    return [
        'cars' => [],
      ] + parent::defaultFieldSettings();
  }
```